# How to make a function lie in the interval [0,1]

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

Is there a way to convert a function g(x) so that the result lies between [0,1]? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Multiply it by zero.

Comment: Or compose it with the absolute value of $\sin$, that is, use $x\mapsto |\sin(g(x))|$.

Answer (score 2):

If you function is $\ge 0$, use the function 
$$
x\to \frac x{1+|x|}
$$

In general, use
$$
x\to \frac 12 \left(1+ \frac x{1+|x|}\right)
$$
You hence have a one to one transformation: [link to the plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%5B1%2F2%281%2Bx%2F%281%2B%7Cx%7C%29%29%2C+%7Bx%2C-20%2C20%7D%5D)

[image]

---

Another one is of course
$$
x\to \frac 1\pi \arctan x + \frac 12
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for help! In fact I have a differential equation. I apply Ito and I get g(ft) and I need a way to make sure that this lies between [0,1]. Sorry, I have not much idea about the science and I m in trouble now!

Comment: can you open a new question for this one?

Comment: I m sorry...what do you mean open a new question...sorry, I m new in this website and I m not very familiar with the rules. Sure your answer gives me an idea how to go on. Thank you.

Comment: I have edited with another answer. To understand the way the site works, take the [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: I mean that your problem with Ito formula looks like it is a whole different problem, and deserves more than a commentary ;)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will make a new more detailed question to refer this as well.